# Facebook Insights API to asp.net (not an App)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, facebook, api, facebook-insights

We are trying to help a customer of ours to get their company page FB Insights data out of FB and shown on an Admin website we have for the client. So instead of having to log into FB to see the insights they will be able to see the data (that we put into reports) from the analytics webiste we already have for them.

we just can't figure out how to use the FB API to pull data for an individual fan page in an asp.net application using VB as the programming language.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use Facebook C# SDK and try to access insight object:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/insights/

You have to be admin of App/Page to be able to get this to work.

Comment: our application is unsing VB so more difficult to code with c#